# JSON key is called "true", unable to reference in JavaScript(JSfiddle example)

Tags: javascript, json

First of all, I converted a Plist(XML formatted) to JSON with some online tool, this isn't the problem. I managed to pick the important values from this rather big JSON file. With this important information I am rebuilding a new JSON file that is very lean and contains information I can use for a plug-in — that I will create later.

The plist conversion to JSON is ugly. At some point `<true/>` and `<false/>` are converted to JSON, leaving this in the JSON: `"false":"",` or `"true":"",`.

**I am using jQuery**

check JSfiddle for an example [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TbVdG/)

or here

```
// Simplified (not really a JSON file, but this will do it for explaining) 
var themeJSON = {
    "item": {
        "false": "",
    },
};

// I need to know if its enabled: "true" or disabled: "false"

// function for checking if this is the default option
function checkDefault() {
    // true is a keyword!
    if (themeJSON.item.true) {
        return "1";
    // so is false!
    } else(themeJSON.item.false) {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Maybe I use some other function such as find() ?

**updated for answer:**
thanks to the comments, this is what I have now:

```
function checkDefault() {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty("true")) {
        return "1";
    } else if(item.hasOwnProperty("false")) {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object property has a name which is a reserved keyword, the array index notation can be used to reference it.

A way of checking whether `item` has a property named `false`:

```
> themeJSON.item.hasOwnProperty("false");
true
```

This not ideal because a single object could have both a `false` property and a `true` property.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the property name as a string:

```
if (themeJSON.item['true']) {
  return '1';
}
else if (themeJSON.item['false']) {
    return "0";
}
```

*edit* — a comment correctly points out that though accessing the properties by string value will indeed work, your code is otherwise flawed.  If the properties are really being given empty string values, then what you really need is a way to test whether the property is there at all, and not (as this code does) just check the *value* of the property:

```
if (typeof themeJSON.item['true'] !== 'undefined') { ... }
```

or, alternatively:

```
if ('true' in themeJSON.item) { ... }
```

An explicit check for equality against the empty string would do too:

```
if (themeJSON.item['true'] === '') { ... }
```

Comment: @Olegas well no, it won't, but that's not really what the OP was asking about.  However I'll update the answer to reflect your valid point.

Comment: @user465395 well, the two tricks I posted definitely do work, though your solution is fine too (the ".hasOwnProperty()" function).

Answer (score 0):

In JS, `foo.bar` is the equivalent of `foo['bar']`. Therefose:

```
if (themeJSON.item['true'] === "")
```

Note the need for `===` as `false == ""` but `false !== ""`.

Also, I must nitpick. `themeJSON` is no longer JSON since it's not a string - it's just another JavaScript object. You shouldn't confuse those two.

Comment: I understand that themeJSON is not JSON, the fact is I am dealing with 900+ lines of JSON(tidied). For this purpose I am using themeJSON, to simplify the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function checkDefault() {
    // true is a keyword!
    if ("true" in themeJSON.item) {
        return "1";
    // so is false!
    } else if ("false" in themeJSON.item) {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've made my own jsFiddle sample with my code and it works just fine! http://jsfiddle.net/p2Lqn/2/